# Copy values from textboxes to datagridview automatically

Tags: c#, datagridview, textbox

In a button click event I put this code to copy textboxes values into a three columns in a datagridview. In my textbox4 I put manually the number of row. Is it possible to do it automatically? I mean select the next row and copy values? This is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int row = int.Parse(textBox4.Text);

        dataGridView1["HomeOdd", row].Value = textBox1.Text;
        dataGridView1["DrawOdd", row].Value = textBox2.Text;
        dataGridView1["AwayOdd", row].Value = textBox3.Text;

        dataGridView1.Refresh();


    }
```

Thanks and Have a fantastic sunday!

Comment: do you want to remove 4th text-box or button

Comment: 4th textbox. Is it also possible to add this event In my form load event, when my datagridview is filled with my data? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to add data at the end of datagridview

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //it will at end of datagridview
    int row = (DataGridView1.Rows.Count)+1;

    dataGridView1["HomeOdd", row].Value = textBox1.Text;
    dataGridView1["DrawOdd", row].Value = textBox2.Text;
    dataGridView1["AwayOdd", row].Value = textBox3.Text;

    dataGridView1.Refresh();
}
```

you can also add on selection

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //its give you selected row no
    int row = (datagridview.CurrentCell.RowIndex)+1;

    dataGridView1["HomeOdd", row].Value = textBox1.Text;
    dataGridView1["DrawOdd", row].Value = textBox2.Text;
    dataGridView1["AwayOdd", row].Value = textBox3.Text;

    dataGridView1.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: I got an error: "+= is a not valid term for this expression" (more or less is this). How can I do?

Comment: So, I tried your code: first code generate this error: "Index out of range . Requested non-negative value and less than the size of the collection ."

Comment: 2nd code generate error like before. How Can I fix it? Thanks a lot

Comment: @Marci  code updated i think now it have to work fine